# CUDA Installation on WSL Environment Taking Unusually Long

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

So I want to install CUDA on a WSL Ubuntu environment so I can run TensorFlow on my GPU. Since TensorFlow only supports up to version 11.8, I used the commands from [the following tutorial.](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_local) On the very last command, after I started it, it started sending a bunch of Get requests then unpacking a bunch of packages. However, on one of these packages (called libcublas-dev-11-8), its unpacking has been running for around 21 hours now. Task Manager shows it is taking up less than 1% of CPU, around 300MB of RAM, and little to no disk usage. Is there something wrong with the installation going on, or should I just let it run longer? If there is something wrong, how can I fix it, or if I should just let it run, how long will it take?

UPDATE: After killing the process via computer reboot and rerunning the command, it seemed to finish the unpacking of libcublas-dev-11-8 but now seems to be stuck on "Selecting previously unselected package libnvjpeg-dev-11-8." This time, it is also taking up 10 gb of RAM, though still no CPU usage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What version is the WSL kernel?

Comment: When I run "wsl --version" it says 5.15.133.1-1 as the kernel version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I fixed the problem is a little weird. While the program was still running, I restarted my computer and then ran that last command again. It started unpacking the same files, starting at the libcublas-dev-11-8 package it was having trouble with earlier. It finished that quickly however, and later finished everything else.